# How do I freeze a live thumbnail using DWMWA_FREEZE_REPRESENTATION?

Tags: windows, api, winapi, dwm

I'm successfully projecting another windows' content (in my test case now, notepad) into my own window. It works just fine.

What I don't manage to do is freezing it, as offered by the API using `DwmSetWindowAttribute` ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/nf-dwmapi-dwmsetwindowattribute)) with the parameter `DWMWA_FREEZE_REPRESENTATION` ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwmapi/ne-dwmapi-dwmwindowattribute)), which equals 15 according to the internet.

`dwmSetWindowAttribute(MyWindow,15,@Value,1)`

I've tried literally all the variants. Sending 1 byte, sending 4 bytes, value 1, 0, "maxdword" etc. etc. The return value is always `-2147024809`, which - unless i get that wrong - means "Invalid Parameter".

Using a workaround by grabbing the DC of the window I am projecting isn't an option due to the slowness of BitBlt. I've stumbled across dwm thumbnails after looking for reasonably quickly implementable alternatives.

Searching the internet for `DWMWA_FREEZE_REPRESENTATION` does not yield me anything useful at all, as if no one else even tries using it. I guess my question will soon be the number one search result on google.

Running on Windows 10's May update.

How can I get this to work?

Comment: The return code is `0x8007'0057` -- HRESULT codes are meant to be read in hex not as negative decimal integers.

Comment: Yes, you're right. That doesn't really help me solving the problem, though. :D

Comment: Is my question bad? Does no one have an answer? What is going on?

Comment: Probably the only people with an answer are the ones with NDA access to Microsoft source code... and they may be concerned about that NDA when considering posting an answer publicly.

Comment: @BenVoigt I've been asking on MSDN too, after receiving this blaring silence ... and after two days now been told that it has been submitted as an issue. Apparently it's an actual bug?

Comment: Well, the public-facing documentation clearly lacks information on the buffer you're supposed to pass to `DWMWA_FREEZE_REPRESENTATION`.  The issue could well be "insufficient documentation" and not "bug in the code".

Comment: @BenVoigt I don't know. The function works in general, I've checked the other available parameters. I found the documentation to be sufficient, though the function itself doesn't quite feel thought-through. Anyhow, I will update this question as soon as I know more.

Comment: The doc isn't sufficient.  Compare to `DWMWA_NCRENDERING_POLICY` which says "The *`pvAttribute`* parameter points to a value from the **`DWMNCRENDERINGPOLICY`** enumeration" or `DWMWA_TRANSITIONS_FORCEDISABLED` which says "The *`pvAttribute`* parameter points to a value of type **`BOOL`**"   For `DWMWA_FREEZE_REPRESENTATION` the documentation doesn't tell you what a correct value for *`pvAttribute`* is.

Comment: I wanted to mention that an msdn moderator confirmed the value is boolean and that I am still waiting for updates I can put here as well.

Comment: Unfortunately there are multiple "boolean" types in the Win32 API.  Should it be `BOOL` (4 bytes, `TRUE == !FALSE`)?  `BOOLEAN` (1 byte, `TRUE == !FALSE`)?  `VARIANT_BOOL` (4 bytes, `True == ~False`)

Comment: @BenVoigt BOOL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 3rd and 4th parameters are really `BOOL*` and `sizeof(BOOL)`, but the 1st needs to be a UWP window. `DWMWA_FREEZE_REPRESENTATION` is only available for UWP windows which is not metioned in document.

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/90690fd3-ec2c-4d2c-a9ad-eafc484427ce/how-do-i-freeze-a-live-thumbnail-using-dwmwafreezerepresentation?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues

Thank you for your help! On both sites! :D